# Graph partitioning in groups of n vertices each

Tags: algorithm, graph, partitioning

Is there any graph partitioning method that can partition a graph in groups of maximum n vertices.

Example : I have a graph with 1000 vertices and I want to partition it in subgraphs with maximum 100 vertices. There can be 2 subgraphs with 50 vertices each if algorithm find this being better.

I found a method with k-means and after k-means to "calibrate" clusters in such way to have 100 vertices in each cluster but I think this method is time consuming.

Any ideas ?

Edit: Ok, maybe it was wrong to ask for subgraphs. Just imagine how kmeans work , I want to partition my graph in small groups , after partition I solve TSP problem in each group and then link every group with nearest group and apply 3opt moves for groups center. But to do this I need a partition method to find groups with max n vertices ; algorithm can find k groups with n vertices and if there are some vertices free it will make another group with what left. Vertices must be close eachother not random selected.

Comment: is there any difference between a subgraph and a path?

Comment: *"There can be 2 subgraphs with 50 vertices each if algorithm find this being better."* - What is better/worse for the algorithm? What are your constraints/objective? It is not possible to answer your question as it is, there are no information on the problem - Do I have the right to makes subgraph with one vertex? If so, why is not a "good solution"? Do the subgraph have to be convex? If not, why not simply create 10 random subgraph of 100 vertices each? Please update your question to have a **clearly defined problem**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make research for this. I remember an heuristic algorithm called Kernighan-Lin that can serve your purpose. Unfortunate you need to generalize it and the time is really bad. I believe it is around O(N^3).

Also another more professional but complicated approach is to use Spectral Partitioning. There is a very detailed article about this topic that you can use on the Direct Science website. Here is a link to this topic: [Spectral partitioning works: Planar graphs and finite
element meshes](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379506003454).

I hope this will help you in your quest. But I am warning you this is not a simple matter. Good Luck!

Comment: I saw those methods but i will try to modify some sort of single-linkage clustering method to achieve my goals.